# couldn't debug stored procedure manually

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a problem when debugging stored procedure using SQL server Management Studio 2008. I pressed ALT+ F5 and I get "Query executed successfully" message. It's not hitting any breakpoint. Could you please let me know what could be the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely a firewall issue, or you do not have permissions to debug

This may provide some insight for you as well

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1bhybwz(v=VS.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027